# data.table NOT summarizing properly by two columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have this problem with `data.table` which is driving me crazy recently. It looks like a bug but may be I'm missing something obvious here.

I have the following data frame:

```
# First some data
data <- data.table(structure(list(
  month = structure(c(1356998400, 1356998400, 1356998400, 
                      1359676800, 1354320000, 1359676800, 1359676800, 1356998400, 1356998400, 
                      1354320000, 1354320000, 1354320000, 1359676800, 1359676800, 1359676800, 
                      1356998400, 1359676800, 1359676800, 1356998400, 1359676800, 1359676800, 
                      1359676800, 1359676800, 1354320000, 1354320000), class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                 "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
  portal = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
             TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
             TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE
  ), 
  satisfaction = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 
                   9L, 2L, 8L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 9L, 
                   10L, 10L)), 
                  .Names = c("month", "portal", "satisfaction"), 
                  row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = "data.frame"))
```

I want to summarize it by both `portal` and `month`. Summarizing with good old `tapply` works as expected - I get 3x2 matrix with results for Dec-2012 and Jan-Feb 2013:

```
> tapply(data$satisfaction, list(data$month, data$portal), mean)
           FALSE      TRUE
2012-12-01   8.5  8.000000
2013-01-01  10.0 10.000000
2013-02-01   9.0  9.545455
```

Summarizing with `by` argument of `data.table` does not:

```
> data[, mean(satisfaction), by = 'month,portal']
   month      portal        V1
1: 2013-01-01  FALSE 10.000000
2: 2013-02-01   TRUE  9.000000
3: 2013-01-01   TRUE 10.000000
4: 2012-12-01  FALSE  8.500000
5: 2012-12-01   TRUE  7.333333
6: 2013-02-01   TRUE  9.666667
7: 2013-02-01  FALSE  9.000000
8: 2012-12-01   TRUE 10.000000
```

As you see, it returns a data table with *8* values, not *6* as expected; values where `portal == TRUE` and `month == 2012-02-01` are duplicated, for example.

Interestingly enough, if I limit this just to 2013's data, everything works as expected:

```
> data[month >= ymd(20130101), mean(satisfaction), by = 'month,portal']
        month portal        V1
1: 2013-01-01   TRUE 10.000000
2: 2013-01-01  FALSE 10.000000
3: 2013-02-01   TRUE  9.545455
4: 2013-02-01  FALSE  9.000000
```

I am puzzled beyond believe :). Could somebody please help me?

Comment: Use `by=list(month, portal)`

Comment: Firstly, `data[, mean(satisfaction), by = list(month, portal)]` produces the same (incorrect) result. Secondly, according to `data.table` help, both syntaxes are supported: "by - A single unquoted column name, a list() of expressions of column names, a single character string containing comma separated column names, or a character vector of column names."

Comment: Converting your POSIX column to Date (`as.Date`) seems to work. I think data.table is (correctly? incorrectly?) splitting some hairs on whether some of those dates are "equal".

Comment: Thanks @joran. This is strange, really - e.g. when I do `table(c(1356998400, 1356998400, 1356998400, 1359676800, 1354320000, 1359676800, 1359676800, 1356998400, 1356998400,                   1354320000, 1354320000, 1354320000, 1359676800, 1359676800, 1359676800, 1356998400, 1359676800, 1359676800, 1356998400, 1359676800, 1359676800, 1359676800, 1359676800, 1354320000, 1354320000))` I get exactly three different values.

Comment: Also not clear why it *stops* splitting the hairs if presented with a smaller subset of the same data. It's the second behavior that caused me to spend long time to finally debug this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is a known issue that was solved in data.table 1.8.7 (not in CRAN yet as of this writing).

From data.table [NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable):

> ```
> BUG FIXES
>
>     <...>
>
> o   setkey could sort 'double' columns (such as POSIXct) incorrectly when not the
>     last column of the key, #2484. In data.table's C code :
>         x[a] > x[b]-tol
>     should have been :
>         x[a]-x[b] > -tol  [or  x[b]-x[a] < tol ]
>     The difference may have been machine/compiler dependent. Many thanks to statquant
>     for the short reproducible example. Test added.
> ```

After updating to 1.8.7 with `install.packages("data.table", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")`, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 5):

The problem seems to be with the sorting. When I load `data` and do `setkey`:

```
setkey(data, "month", "portal")

# > data
#          month portal satisfaction
#  1: 2012-12-01   TRUE           10
#  2: 2012-12-01  FALSE            9
#  3: 2012-12-01  FALSE            8
#  4: 2012-12-01   TRUE            2
#  5: 2012-12-01   TRUE           10
#  6: 2012-12-01   TRUE           10
#  7: 2013-01-01   TRUE           10
#  8: 2013-01-01   TRUE           10
#  9: 2013-01-01   TRUE           10
# 10: 2013-01-01   TRUE           10
# 11: 2013-01-01   TRUE           10
# 12: 2013-01-01   TRUE           10
# 13: 2013-01-01  FALSE           10
# 14: 2013-02-01   TRUE            9
# 15: 2013-02-01   TRUE            9
# 16: 2013-02-01  FALSE            9
# 17: 2013-02-01   TRUE           10
# 18: 2013-02-01   TRUE           10
# 19: 2013-02-01   TRUE           10
# 20: 2013-02-01   TRUE           10
# 21: 2013-02-01   TRUE           10
# 22: 2013-02-01   TRUE            9
# 23: 2013-02-01   TRUE           10
# 24: 2013-02-01   TRUE            9
# 25: 2013-02-01   TRUE            9
#          month portal satisfaction
```

You see that the `portal` column is not properly sorted. When I do `setkey` again,

```
setkey(data, "month", "portal")

# I get this warning message:
Warning message:
In setkeyv(x, cols, verbose = verbose) :
  Already keyed by this key but had invalid row order, key rebuilt. 
  If you didn't go under the hood please let datatable-help know so 
  the root cause can be fixed.
```

Now, the `data` columns seem properly sorted by key columns:

```
# > data
#          month portal satisfaction
#  1: 2012-12-01  FALSE            9
#  2: 2012-12-01  FALSE            8
#  3: 2012-12-01   TRUE           10
#  4: 2012-12-01   TRUE            2
#  5: 2012-12-01   TRUE           10
#  6: 2012-12-01   TRUE           10
#  7: 2013-01-01  FALSE           10
#  8: 2013-01-01   TRUE           10
#  9: 2013-01-01   TRUE           10
# 10: 2013-01-01   TRUE           10
# 11: 2013-01-01   TRUE           10
# 12: 2013-01-01   TRUE           10
# 13: 2013-01-01   TRUE           10
# 14: 2013-02-01  FALSE            9
# 15: 2013-02-01   TRUE            9
# 16: 2013-02-01   TRUE            9
# 17: 2013-02-01   TRUE           10
# 18: 2013-02-01   TRUE           10
# 19: 2013-02-01   TRUE           10
# 20: 2013-02-01   TRUE           10
# 21: 2013-02-01   TRUE           10
# 22: 2013-02-01   TRUE            9
# 23: 2013-02-01   TRUE           10
# 24: 2013-02-01   TRUE            9
# 25: 2013-02-01   TRUE            9
#          month portal satisfaction
```

So, it seems to be an issue with sortting a `POSIXct + logical` types?

```
data[, mean(satisfaction), by=list(month, portal)]

#         month portal        V1
# 1: 2012-12-01  FALSE  8.500000
# 2: 2012-12-01   TRUE  8.000000
# 3: 2013-01-01  FALSE 10.000000
# 4: 2013-01-01   TRUE 10.000000
# 5: 2013-02-01  FALSE  9.000000
# 6: 2013-02-01   TRUE  9.545455
```

I therefore think there's a bug.

Comment: Yeah, I was just about to leave a comment saying that if @MatthewDowle doesn't weigh in on this in a day or two, the OP should probably post this question on the data.table mailing list.

Comment: Aha! Thanks Arun, that indeed seems to be the case. I'll report it as a bug to the mailing list. We'll wait for Matthew to respond just in case before accepting your answer.

Comment: It may be related to this bug, which, coincidence or not, was opened today: https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2552&group_id=240&atid=975